# can't display my message with fetch api reactJS/nodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch, fetch-api, display

I want to use a fetch API call.
To try if it works I try to show a message.

In my nodeJs server i've:

```
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
res.send({
    message: 'Hi'
})
```

})

In my frontend folder, in my app.js:

```
 import React, {useState} from 'react';

  const App = () => {

  const [message, setMsg] = useState('');
  
  const handleClick = async () => {
    console.log('click');

    fetch('/api')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`${error}`)
      })
      .then(json => console.log(json))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Couldn't convert the json: ${error}`)
      });
    setMsg(message);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
          Button
        </button>
        <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Everythings is ok, when i load my app in my browser, i've no error in my inspector,
when i click on my button:
my console shows:

> click

my json shows:

> {message: 'Hi'}
> >message: "Hi"
> >[[Prototype]]: Object

But my message doesn't works for `<p>{message}<p>`

when i put 'test' in `setMsg(console.log('test'))` it works.
when i put it in `<p>test</p>` it works

I really don't understand my `<p>{message}</p>` doesn't display..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
const handleClick = async () => {
    console.log('click');
    fetch('/api')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`${error}`)
      })
      .then(json => {
        setMsg(json.message)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Couldn't convert the json: ${error}`)
      });
};
```

Comment: I didn't think about it... thanks !